# shape1.canvas1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, paintLine)

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying something like below:

```
shape1.canvas1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, paintLine);
```

to

```
this["shape"+i].canvas[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, paintLine);
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be:

```
this["shape"+i]["canvas"+j].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, paintLine);
         // or ["canvas"+i]
```

Comment: If that helped please accept the answer to close the question.